# model associations in rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

In my application a user can create an appointment.

```
class User
    has_many :appointments
end

class Appointment
    belongs_to :user
end
```

However, a user can also join another appointment created by another user.

Could someone recommend a way to set up my models?

I've been reading through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and cannot find the correct association.

I'm really keen to do this the rails way, rather than hacking my application about.

Would has_and_belongs_to_many be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want to use [`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-association) with some kind of model describing the relationship between users and appointments:

```
# models/user_appointment.rb
class UserAppointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :appointment
end

# models/appointment.rb
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_appointments
  has_many :users, :through => :user_appointments
end

# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_appointments
  has_many :appointments, :through => :user_appointments
end
```

Of course, you'll probably also want to represent the owner of the appointment. You could expand your `Appointment` model to reflect who actually owns it. You could provide a relationship field in `UserAppointment` to describe whether a user is an owner or subscriber, but it might be easier to simply add a [`belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association) relationship to the appointment model:

```
# models/appointment.rb
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_appointments
  has_many :users, :through => :user_appointments
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Comment: Sounds good. Just typed, didn't test--let me know if I need to adjust or clarify anything!

Comment: should i create some new fields in my models? originally in user i had 'name' and 'email'. whilst appointments had 'user_id' and various appointment info fields..

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a database migration for the `user_appointments` table and add an `owner_id` column to the `appointments` table

Comment: i'm getting an error at 'belongs_to :owner, :as => :user'
    Unknown key: as

Comment: You're right--I should've been using `:class_name` for a `:belongs_to`. I should also mention that `:owner` isn't really being used in the example above (e.g., I haven't added a reciprocal relationship in `User` to describe `:owned_appointments` or something like that...but this would be easy to do if needed)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9003/discussion-between-gibo-and-rjz)